# Clear path on GoogleMap object - android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

The problem is that the map doesn't get cleared each time I try to draw a different route so I get one route drawn on top of the other.

I've already spent too much time trying to solve it. After been testing what other users suggest finally nothing seems to work. 
This is what basically I've tried:

- I'm calling the `googleMap.clear()` method
- I'm also maintaining a reference to each polyline added on the map to invoke later the `polyline.remove()` method when drawing a new route.

I have a web service which is retreiving data from a database, it returns an `ArrayList<Stop>`, the stop object represents a bus stop containing the information needed to draw the route on the map.

The application doesn't consume google web services directly, each stop object has a field called "polyline" and the app decodes this polyline string and retrieves an `ArrayList<LatLng>`

Let me show you the snippet of code I wrote to do it.

```
public void drawRoute(ArrayList<Stop> stops){
    googleMap.clear();
    removePolylines();
        for(int x = 0; x< stops.size(); x++){
            Stop stop = stops.get(x);
            if(x != stops.size() -1){                    
                ArrayList<LatLng> routePoints = DataParser.decodePolyline(stop.getPolyline());
                Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions.addAll(routePoints));
                polylines.add(polyline);                    
            }
            addMarker(stop);
        }            
}
```

...

```
private void removePolylines(){
    for(Polyline polyline: polylines){
            polyline.remove();
    }
}
```

I also attached some screenshots to explain better what the problem is.

[image]

There's no problem drawing a route the first time...

[image]

But then when I press the back button and choose another route id...

[image]

As you can see by the red circles the previous route is still on the map, the weird thing is that the markers doesn't appear anymore but the route does.

How can I get rid of this problem? 
Is there a better solution to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at another similar answer, it looks like you just need to add `polylines.remove(polyline);` after your `polyline.remove();` statement. For reference, here is the other similar question: [Remove the last plotted line from Google Map Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024427/remove-the-last-plotted-line-from-google-map-android)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: @Andrew Kulpa I've just found a solution, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys problem solved, after struggle a lot, I realized how easy the solution is.

The problem occurs in this line:

```
Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions.addAll(routePoints));
```

The thing is that the `polylineOptions` object is declared at the top of the class and is initilalized in the constructor. So, every time the `drawRoute(ArrayList<Stop> stops)` method is executed a new `ArrayList<LatLng> routePoints` is added to it.

This is the reason why te routes appear drawn one on top of the other. I also found out that there's no need to invoke the `googleMap.clear()` and `removePolylines()` methods, at least in this concrete case.

The refactored code looks like this:

```
public void drawRoute(ArrayList<Stop> stops){
    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    for(int x = 0; x< stops.size(); x++){
        Stop stop = stops.get(x);
        if(x != stops.size() -1){
            ArrayList<LatLng> routePoints = DataParser.decodePolyline(stop.getPolyline());
            googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions.addAll(routePoints));                
        }
        addMarker(stop);
    }
}
```

You see the difference? 
The `PolylineOptions` object is declared and initialized locally within the method.

I hope this will be useful for someone else.